# using library https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel faced exception when updated android studio 3.0

Tags: android

```
10-30 12:12:17.610 26881-26881/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-30 12:12:17.696 26881-26881/com.kidsapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.kidsapp-2/lib/arm
10-30 12:12:17.700 26881-26881/com.kidsapp D/ActivityThread: BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{32a37bc com.kidsapp}}
10-30 12:12:17.701 26881-26881/com.kidsapp V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{d5d3345 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2ac0a9a {com.kidsapp/com.kidsapp.Main2Activity}} startsNotResumed=false
10-30 12:12:17.717 26881-26881/com.kidsapp V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{d5d3345 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2ac0a9a {com.kidsapp/com.kidsapp.Main2Activity}}: app=android.app.Application@44113a8, appName=com.kidsapp, pkg=com.kidsapp, comp={com.kidsapp/com.kidsapp.Main2Activity}, dir=/data/app/com.kidsapp-2/base.apk
10-30 12:12:17.754 26881-26881/com.kidsapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-30 12:12:17.772 26881-26903/com.kidsapp I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
10-30 12:12:17.786 26881-26881/com.kidsapp E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!
10-30 12:12:17.878 26881-26881/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-30 12:12:17.881 26881-26881/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.kidsapp, PID: 26881
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kidsapp/com.kidsapp.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:20171)
                                                       at com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel.initializeView(DraggablePanel.java:263)
                                                       at com.kidsapp.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:27)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:20171) 
                                                       at com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel.initializeView(DraggablePanel.java:263) 
                                                       at com.kidsapp.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:27) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:20171) 
                                                       at com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel.initializeView(DraggablePanel.java:263) 
                                                       at com.kidsapp.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:27) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:666)
                                                       at com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView.initializeAttributes(DraggableView.java:680)
                                                       at com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView.<init>(DraggableView.java:85)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                       at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:20171) 
                                                       at com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel.initializeView(DraggablePanel.java:263) 
                                                       at com.kidsapp.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:27) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
10-30 12:12:17.892 26881-26881/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26881 SIG: 9
```

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kidsapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev182-1.22.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.pedrovgs:draggablepanel:1.9'
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
    <com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel
        android:id="@+id/draggable_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Click Me" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.kidsapp;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Button button;
        final DraggablePanel draggablePanel;
        draggablePanel = findViewById(R.id.draggable_panel);

        draggablePanel.setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager());
        draggablePanel.setTopFragment(new One());
        draggablePanel.setBottomFragment(new Two());
        draggablePanel.setTopViewHeight(300);
        draggablePanel.initializeView();


        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                draggablePanel.closeToLeft();
            }
        },100);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        draggablePanel.maximize();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: to get better help, please explain more about your problem instead of just pasting codes.. What do you want to do and what is your problem.

Comment: problem is solved. This library is deprecated now that's why giving this exception.

Comment: I want to make a draggable panel like youtube app and use [this](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) library. it works good when i am using buildToolsVersion "26.0.1" but after updating android studio to 3.0 buildToolsVersion changed to "26.0.2" which gives android.view.InflateException

Comment: OK, update your question by adding that details.

Comment: Have you found any solution.

Comment: @HassanShah Have you found any solution?

Comment: this library is deprecated in new from API 26.

Answer (score 1):

```
Navigate to Android Studion -> File -> New -> Import Project and choose the draggablepanel folder from the library. Update the support dependency in the draggablepanel build.gradle and remove com.github.pedrovgs:draggablepanel:1.9 from you application build.gradle. Include the imported module in your app build.gradle and settings.gradle as follows:

implementation project(':draggablepanel')
include ':app', ':draggablepanel'
```